# Archery Master is affected by what other skills?

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

In the game, the skill Archery master states the following:
[image: Archery Master description]

So, if I use the bow normally, it will consume the arrow, correct?
What other hunter skills will trigger the "No longer consume Normal Arrows" effect?

Will Arrow Master, Multishot, Predator shot and Devastation shot consume normal arrows if I have Archery Master?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, special arrows will still be consumed. However, you can upgrade the ability to get even more damage **and** for it not to consume other types of arrows (each upgrade expands the array of arrow types that can be saved).